# Is there is any way to get the old database from phpmyadmin after uninstall xampp?

Tags: mysql, xampp

I forgot to keep a backup from my database before uninstalling xampp and installing a new one.

So I’m wondering if I can get back the old database that I made before.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the directories and files still there?

Comment: Only the htdocs still there.

Comment: If there is nothing in the mysql folder, then you lost it

Comment: I only have the folder of my project from data folder but when I’m put it back in the new data folder it goes error “the table doesn’t exist in engine”

Comment: Ok! (Updated news) I found the old data folder

Comment: Edit your question and post what data (files) you have to recover from.